# Decode QR-Code in WPF By Zxing

Tags: wpf

What is the proper way to decode QR Code from Bitmap Image?

```
 IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
 var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("output.jpg");
 var result = reader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);
```

This is QR Code Decoding in C# With ZXing.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install **.NET QR Code Barcode Reader & Scanner** from http://www.barcodelib.com/net_barcode_reader/barcodes/qrcode.html

I have seen the same working in one of my clients WPF projects. You can give it a try.

**Features :**

- Easily read & scan QR-Code barcodes in .NET applications.
- Quickly scan & decode QR Code 2d barcodes from specified area inside the image document.
- Decoding & reading QR Code barcode images in JPEG, GIF, PNG, BMP, TIFF file formats.
- 100% build in C#.NET, complying with .NET 2.0 and later versions.
- Complete sample C#.net, VB.net sample codes for Visual C# & VB.NET developers.
- Mature & reliable QR Code .NET Barcode Reader Component since 2003.

Comment: That's a borderline advert, and it doesn't answer the question how to use ZXing in WPF at all. (Though the question isn't really clear, either. Bitmap type doesn't belong to WPF; it's used in Windows Forms.)

Comment: For the record, the real answer is (assuming that you use a .NET Framework project): 1) Install NuGet package `ZXing.Net`; 2) Use type `ZXing.Presentation.BarcodeReader` from assembly zxing.presentation.dll, which natively supports `BitmapSource` (just like `ZXing.BarcodeReader` natively supports `Bitmap`).