# C# - Upload video and read QR codes in it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with a project that it's new for me and I didn't do something like this in the past.
The purpose is to upload a video to a webservice or webapi (in .NET) and scan it looking for QR codes. The video is recorded from a drone without internet connection so the only thing I see difficult is to go through the video and read the QRs that appear in it.

Thanks !

Comment: What have you tried, and where do you run into problems? What is your code? Is there any error messages or compilation errors?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is far too broad for Stack Overflow - we don't write code for people, though we're happy to help if you have more specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like there are two parts to this question:

#### 1. Getting an image from a video

I suppose you manage to do this since you did not provide any info on the video file format.

#### 2. Detecting a QR code in an image.

Multiple options exist:

1. Use the AForgeTry using AForge.NET library for capturing the video from your webcam, and then ZXing.Net library for reading the QR codes: see [QR code webcam scanner c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424360/qr-code-webcam-scanner-c-sharp)
2. See [Decode QR-Code in WPF By Zxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717500/decode-qr-code-in-wpf-by-zxing/40718310#40718310)

Comment: Bernard,
Yeah ! The problem is not the code, the question focuses on whether it is possible to do this, otherwise I would look for another alternative but with your answer I see that there is a way to do it. Thank you very much